Vercel Deployment 404: Not Found
enter image description here
Hi Guys, i want to deploy my html project at vercel. The deployment status is successful, but i can't see the result of my project and there's just a 404: NOT_FOUND.
I think there's something wrong with my project structure.
This my project structure
i've research some project structure, and result of my research, the project structure is free, there's nothing some specific provision.
Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank you

There is nothing wrong with the Project structure, make sure the url is correctly entered.
